# Prove that $\mathcal{BFA}(X, \mathfrak{M}, \mu)$ is a linear space on which $\|.\|_{var}$ is a norm.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation

Show that $\mathcal{BFA}(X, \mathfrak{M}, \mu)$ is a linear space on which $\|.\|_{var}$ is a norm. then show that this normed linear space is a Banach space.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Any hints for the triangle inequality proof and the completeness proof ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\nu, \omega \in \mathcal{BAF}(X, \mathfrak{M}, \mu)$. Fix a disjoint, finite collection of measurable sets $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^n$ and show that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n|[\nu+\omega](E_k)| \leq
\sum_{k=1}^n |\nu(E_k)| + \sum_{k=1}^n|\omega(E_k)| 
$$
Taking the supremum on either side will give you the desired inequality.

Comment: what about the completeness?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that part. I have to go for now but if I have time I'll take a look tomorrow!